Instead of seeing time as a continuous, directional “arrow” moving forward, could time be conceptualized as a series of distinct “moments” experience
In this view, time isn’t a flow or a trajectory but rather an accumulation of discrete, experiential “points” that we set for one point to another… Each moment exists on its own, and our sense of “movement” through time might arise from the way we connect these moments in memory. Time being a necessity that arises from consciousness through perception and perspective.

The idea has been floating around for a while: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronon

From what I understand, time isn't in motion, it doesn't have directions, it's not "flowing", really, but that's how you can use it as a metric for something.  Time is now.  Right now.  Time is always this moment.  Never changing, only now.

One knows that each movie film is composed as a discrete sequence of distinct images. But when presenting about 16 images per second or more, the viewer perceives a continous flow. Similarly I understand your question.

The general approach in physics is to model time as a continuous
parameter, represented by real numbers, not integers. This approach
is the basis of nearly all scientific theories which rely on the
concept of differential equations: Newton’s mechanics,
electrodynamics, quantum mechanics, theory of relativity, …
But
there are also approaches which model times as a discrete lattice,
in particular for the domain beyond the Planck time and Planck
length.

In philosophy Humes bundle theory emphasizes the discreteness of
mental perception, see bundle theory for the quote:
"[...] I may venture to affirm of the rest of mankind, that
they are nothing but a bundle or collection of different             perceptions, which succeed each other with inconceivable rapidity,
and are in a perpetual flux and movement" (A Treatise of Human Nature, Book I, part IV, sec.6)
And similar was already
the claim of the anatta-doctrine (śūnyatā) of Buddhism.

From the viewpoint of neuroscience, time perception and perception of
one’s own biography as a continuous flow needs explanation.
Because no neurobiological process operates instantaneously, each
neuronal processing takes a positive amount of time.

Your post raises a legitimate question.
The answer is not “yes” or
“no”. Each scientific theory has to find out which approach is more
applicable and promising to explain the phenomena under
consideration.


Of course the question of time opens up a vast field
of ideas, since thousands of years and ongoing.

Someone I read a few years ago - maybe Smolin? - wrote something like, "we say that a series of static images gives the illusion of motion; but the reality is opposite: a series of extended process of self-similar motions give the illusion that the perceived motion is composed of static images"

In physics, time is not an arrow and does not move forward. You move forward   in the direction of time, which is one of four dimensions of spacetime. That  model of space and time- at a large scale- is very well-supported by evidence. New ideas about the nature of spacetime suggest that it might be granular in some way, but on a scale that is far too short for your brain to notice. So no, as far as the physics of time is concerned, you are barking up the wrong tree.That all said, the human experience of time is a different matter altogether, and perhaps your perception of it is somewhat like a series of frames.

When I started writing this comment, my time displacement from myself was zero, and when I finished writing this comment, my time displacement from myself was still zero. Where am I supposed to have moved, and why aren't I there when I get there?

@gs your time displacement from your present is always zero. My time displacement from when you typed your comment is 6 hours.

@gs You can move to a different continent, and your "space displacement" from yourself will still be zero as well. Movement and displacement is measured relative to some other reference frame, not yourself.

@HugoRune well said!

The linguist Benjamin Lee Whorf had a well known insight — that there is a tight relationship between a people or culture and their language, also called linguistic relativity.
One of the important pieces of data from which that insight emerged was the enormous difference that English speakers and Hopi speakers had wrt the concept of time:


I find it gratuitous to assume that a Hopi who knows only the Hopi language and the cultural ideas of his own society has the same notions, often supposed to be intuitions, of time and space as we have, and that are generally assumed to be universal. In particular he has no notion or intuition of TIME as a smooth flowing continuum in which everything in the universe proceeds at an equal rate, out of a future into a present and into a past .... After a long and careful analysis the Hopi language is seen to contain no words, grammatical forms, construction or expressions that refer directly to what we call 'time', or to past, present or future ...

Whorf argues that in Hopi units of time are not represented by nouns, but by adverbs or verbs... that all Hopi nouns include the notion of a boundary or outline, and that consequently the Hopi language does not refer to abstract concepts with nouns. This is encoded in Hopi grammar, which does not allow durations of time to be counted in the same way objects are. So instead of saying, for example, "three days," Hopi would say the equivalent of "on the third day," using ordinal numbers. Whorf argues that the Hopi do not consider the process of time passing to produce another new day, but merely as bringing back the daylight aspect of the world.
Wikipedia

The difficulty of digesting this view is that this molding of our thought by English is sufficiently wider than English (see Standard Average European SAE) that it can easily be mistaken as universal though it is in fact cultural.  See Sprachsbund — Federation of related languages
So, the spatialization of time is less an intrinsic property of space-time and more a result of the linguistic patterns of Standard Average European languages or SAE languages such as
English, German, French.
And then the space metaphor that treats time as a physical dimension becomes such an ingrained habit we think it's a priori truth.
Time in SAE
Below are collected some of the linguistic properties of Time in SAE languages and English in particular.
1. Use of Spatial Prepositions

“Ahead of schedule” / “Behind schedule”: These expressions use spatial prepositions ("ahead" and "behind") to describe temporal relationships, implying that time can be navigated like a physical space.
“In the past” / “In the future”: The preposition “in” suggests being contained within a space, mapping temporal reference onto spatial enclosure.

2. Linear Representations

Timelines: In SAE languages, time is often represented as a linear progression, moving from left to right (consistent with the direction of reading in these languages). This aligns with a spatial view where past, present, and future occupy distinct points on a continuum.
“Long day” / “Short time”: These phrases use spatial dimensions of length to convey the passage of time, equating the duration of time with physical extension.

3. Metaphorical Constructs

“Looking forward to the weekend”: This phrase anthropomorphizes time as an object that can be looked at or awaited, implying that time is a space we move through.
“Time flies” / “Time crawls”: These metaphors describe the speed of time using the motion of objects through space, suggesting that time itself has velocity.

4. Directional Expressions

“Moving into the future” / “Leaving the past behind”: These expressions frame time as a path that one travels, reinforcing the idea that time progresses along a spatial vector.
“Approaching the deadline”: This implies that time is a location one can approach, visualizing deadlines as points in space to be reached.

5. Calendar and Clock Terminology

“Quarter past” / “Half past”: These terms for telling time spatialize the clock face as a space through which time travels.
“Turn of the century”: This implies a boundary or a physical turn in the flow of time.

Whorf’s perspective highlights how these linguistic artifacts embed and reinforce the conceptual metaphor of “Time as Space” within SAE (ie Western) cultures.
English (SAE) vs. Hopi
And now, for a  comparison of English (SAE) and Hopi in respect of  linguistic patterns and usages around time.
1. Spatialization of Time

English (SAE languages): Time is often expressed through spatial metaphors. Terms like "a long time," "near future," or "far past" imply that time can be measured, moved through, or exists on a spatial continuum.
Hopi: Whorf argued that Hopi does not conceptualize time in spatial terms. Instead, it treats time as an ongoing process rather than a series of discrete, measurable units or a path. The focus is on events' qualities or their state of being, rather than their position along a timeline.

2. Tense and Temporal Markers

English: Has a clear, standardized system of past, present, and future tenses that denote time explicitly. Verbs are conjugated to indicate when an action occurs, creating a segmented understanding of time.
Hopi: Lacks traditional tenses that indicate time in the way English does. Instead, Hopi uses aspects and modes that denote whether an event is complete, ongoing, expected, or experienced. This reflects an emphasis on the status and certainty of events rather than their temporal position.

3. Concept of Time Units

English: Commonly divides time into units such as seconds, minutes, days, and years, which can be quantified and measured like physical objects.
Hopi: Does not naturally divide time into uniform, quantifiable units. While Hopi speakers can refer to days, seasons, and cycles, they do so with a focus on the natural and experiential flow of time, not as separate, countable objects. Time is embedded in activities and the cycles of nature rather than abstracted into measurable units.

4. Future and Hypothetical Events

English: Uses modal verbs (e.g., “will,” “might,” “could”) to express varying degrees of certainty or possibility about future events.
Hopi: The language distinguishes between actual and hypothetical events through modes of certainty. Statements about the future are framed in terms of expectation or potentiality, reflecting the speaker's perspective on the event's likelihood rather than a straightforward future tense.

5. Perception of Time

English: Conceptualizes time as linear, moving from the past, through the present, and into the future. This linear view supports a narrative that can be plotted or measured against a timeline.
Hopi: Whorf claimed that Hopi speakers view time as more cyclical or process-oriented, embedded within natural cycles (such as seasons and life events) rather than a linear path. This worldview affects how events are understood and communicated, emphasizing their relevance and relationship to the current experience rather than their place in a sequence.

Criticism of Sapir-Whorf
For some reason the current custom on Anglophone sites like this one is that if the names of (Sapir and) Whorf are uttered they must be uttered with mockery or at least condescension.  In keeping with this custom I end with this joke:

There are two kinds of linguists: the monolingual anti-Whorfians, who laugh at Whorf, and the polylingual Whorfians, who laugh in different tongues


Our planet (Earth) is orbiting the Sun, and the Sun is orbiting the Milky Way, something like this...

This is an image of the stars in the Northern night sky, using a long exposure, creating an effect called "star trails"...

We don't head exactly to the middle of it, we head about 12 degrees off, I think.  Towards a star called Vega.
But the created effect, like a tunnel... paints a good picture of the future of Earth.

"So in one year, Earth travels about 584 million miles (940 million km). Since speed is equal to the distance traveled over the time taken, Earth's speed is calculated by dividing 584 million miles (940 million km) by 365.25 days and dividing that result by 24 hours to get miles per hour or km per hour." - Source:  https://www.space.com/33527-how-fast-is-earth-moving.html

We are along for the ride.
Earth doesn't stop, and doesn't change speed on request, and certainly doesn't go backwards.
One way, Earth goes.  With it we go.
Hope that helps.

I don't think this is really answering the question. The question is about if time is continuous; i.e if you can split up 0.1 and 0.2 seconds and find find 0.15 seconds between them. Clearly you can, but does this keep going "all the way down", or is there a base level quantum of time. The Planck time suggests "maybe", it seem impossible to describe times shorter than 5.39×10−44 s (i.e. you can type the number but physics doesn't seem to occur on shorter scales than that)

I may have underexplained, I didn't want to over-explain.  The motion of the Earth is a trajectory, its existence is momentous... in the moment only.  Time progresses along with motion (which is a trajectory).  We inescapably, are a part of this system, along for the ride.  I didn't really get from the OP a need to address the granularity, more the overarching nature of "time".  Arrow?  Yes.  Trajectory?  Joint with motion and existing.

I think you could approach this from 2 directions; is reality quantised (a physics question) and the answer is maybe. Or is memory recorded in discrete steps (a biology question). The idea of discrete moments seems like the core part of the question

Oh.  Ok.  Yes reality is quantised.  But time being emergent (not fundamental)... is analog... perpetual, ongoing.  Only relatively quantizable by comparison to other.

OP: "Time being a necessity that arises from consciousness through perception and perspective."
Time arising from consciousness and measurement like the observation of the passage of day and night is derivative of an existential temporality that is constitutive of cognitive existence.  Since the OP asks about "moments” experienced I think this may be the direction of interest. On the other hand the question may be specifically about moments objectively experienced, say by watching the second hand of a watch, in which case the following is not so relevant.

What is char­acteristic of the 'time' which is accessible to the
ordinary understanding, consists, among other things, precisely in the
fact that it is a pure sequence of "nows", without beginning and
without end, in which the ecstatical character of primordial
temporality has been levelled off. ... If, therefore, we demonstrate
that the 'time' which is accessible to Dasein's common sense is not
primordial, but arises rather from authentic temporality, then, in
accordance with the principle, "a potiori fit denominatio" [naming
based on the stronger], we are justified in designating as
"primordial time" the temporality [being described as 'authentic']. GA2
329

OP: "Each moment exists on its own"
This primordial temporality & existence is how a measured moment can exist objectively in terms of Kantian judgement, e.g. "[existence] is the conjunction of the [notional] thing with perception." note 36 B287 and "In the logical use [existence] is merely the copula of a judgment." A598/B626.
The characteristic of primordial temporality is that living existence holds past, present & future together (in memory and intentionality) in "ecstases", e.g. "Time should be grasped in and of itself as the unity of the three dimensions of future, past and present", Simon Critchley, The Guardian (2009).

In its factical Being, any Dasein is as it already was, and it is
'what' it already was. It is its past, whether explicitly or not.
And this is so not only in that its past is, as it were, pushing
itself along 'behind' it, and that Dasein possesses what is past as a
property which is still present­-at-hand and which sometimes has
after-effects upon it: Dasein 'is' its past in the way of its own
Being, which, to put it roughly, 'historizes' out of its future on
each occasion.2 Whatever the way of being it may have at
the time, and thus with whatever understanding of Being it may
possess, Dasein has grown up both i n t o and i n a traditional way of
interpreting itself: in terms of this it understands itself proximally
and, within a certain range, constantly. GA2
20


The future makes ontologically possible an entity [Dasein] which is in such a
way that it exists understandingly in its potentiality-for-Being.
Projection is basically futural; it does not primarily grasp the
projected possibility thematically just by having it in view, but it
throws itself into it as a possibility. In each case Dasein is
understandingly in the way that it can be. GA2
336

Heidegger develops this theme of authentic temporality from Kant's intuition of time.

"Sense" means "finite intuition." The form of sense, therefore, is
pure receptivity. The internal sense does not receive "from without"
but from the self. In pure receptivity, internal affection [i.e. as the action or process of affecting or being affected] must arise
from the pure self, i.e., be formed in the essence of selfhood as
such, and therefore must constitute the latter. Pure self-affection
provides the transcendental ground-structure [Urstruktur] of the
finite self as such. Therefore, it is absolutely untrue that the mind
exists in such a way that, among other beings, it relates certain
things to itself and in so doing posits itself [Selbstsetzungen
ausübt]. Rather, this line of orientation from the self toward . . .
and back to [the self] first constitutes the mental character of the
mind as a finite self.
It is at once obvious, therefore, that
time as pure self-affection is not found "in the mind" "beside" pure
apperception. On the contrary, as the basis of the possibility of
selfhood, time is already included in pure apperception and first
enables the mind to be what it is.
The pure finite self has in itself a temporal character. Therefore, if
the ego, i.e., pure reason, is essentially temporal, the fundamental
determination which Kant provides for transcendental apperception must
first become intelligible through this temporal character.
Time and the "I think" are no longer opposed to one another as unlike
and incompatible; they are the same. Thanks to the radicalism with
which, in the laying of the foundation of metaphysics, Kant for the
first time subjected time and the "I think," each taken separately, to
a transcendental interpretation, he succeeded in bringing them
together in their primordial identity — without, to be sure, having
seen this identity expressly as such. Kantbuch 196-7

Authentic, or primordial, temporality enables living existence to be what it is (beholding and utilising the 'ecstases' of primordial time), and this allows observations of ordinary cosmological time which may be understood in various ways, for example in bosonic string theory, spacetime is 26-dimensional. The scientific standard time, the caesium standard is defined as the resonant frequency of caesium-133 so if in the heat death scenario there are no more atoms then there is no more time.  These are various descriptions of time, several of which could be true at the same time, and underpin the existential, primordial time within which humans devise the descriptions.


can time be conceptualized as a series of distinct “moments” experience

Time is a direction you can move in, like north-south or forward-reverse. The time direction goes from past to future.
You're a mass moving in that direction at c. Feynman said that that's all mass is: momentum in the direction of future time. Photons have no mass, so they don't move through time.
Ultimately, everything is the superposition of continuous waves.
There is no quantization, any more than space is quantized— which it's not — Planck units notwithstanding.

Those seem like two pretty big assertions; "space is not quantized", "time is not quantized". Do you have any references for that?

But given, as you accept, that we can't distinguish if there is any scale below planck how can you confidently assert there is. There might be of course, but in the absence of any evidence it seems a bit strong to say there is

Agree with @RichardTingle here: you're smashing ontology and epistemology into one amorphous messy goo. If you want to do Zen, Nonduality etc that's fine. Not if you want to do physics or (standard western) philosophy
